Can we solve the Sorites paradox with probability?
Suppose instead of asking whether something is a heap, we consider the probability of that bunch of grains of sand to be recognized as a heap. In that case, we are no longer required to define a clear boundary/definition of what a heap is.
Does this resolve the Sorites paradox, and have philosophers proposed something along those lines?

See Vagueness and probability.

Please add a description of the sorites paradox.

And see D.Edgington, Vagueness by degrees into Vagueness: A reader (1997)

This is usually done with degrees of truth rather than probabilities. They also take intermediate values between 0 and 1 but obey rules of fuzzy logic which are different from probability calculus, see SEP,  Fuzzy logic and vagueness.

Probability is a measure of uncertainty and knowledge, not a measure of truth. When you say that a proposition P has a probability of x, you are saying that it is either true or false but you don't have enough knowledge to say for certain which it is.
The sorites problem is not a problem of knowledge, but a problem of truth. It assumes full knowledge of all the relevant facts. There seems to be a point where there is no matter of fact about whether the object is a heap or not, so probability does not apply. It's not that you don't have sufficient information about the situation to know if it is a heap or not, but that there isn't an actual answer to be had.
Fuzzy logic might apply better. Unlike probability, fuzzy logic actually is about how true something is in a situation where something isn't entirely true or false.

I think the OP was suggesting moving the problem: we can't have a clear truth-value on "That is a heap", but we can have a clear truth-value on "This person recognises that as a heap". Then, introducing probabilities becomes natural: if we take a random person, we can have a probability for "This person recognises that as a heap", and then we can have a slowly-growing probability from 1 grain -> proba 0 to lots of grain -> proba close to 1.

The sorites (and vagueness altogether) can be construed as a problem of ignorance. That's the epistemicist view of vagueness.


We consider the probability of that bunch of grains of sand to be recognized as a heap

I think you run into issues like:

Who is doing the recognizing?
How does that person know what a heap is, if a heap is defined by the probability that they, themselves, will call it a heap?

A common resolution to the sorites paradox is to deny that there are any heaps, there are just assortments of other objects that humans are likely to call heaps, which is potentially along the lines of your question.
SEP: Ordinary Objects and SEP: Problem of the many have discussion & sources for the advantages and disadvantages of taking that stance.

Fuzzy logic dissolves (rather than solves) the paradox. This is because under classical logic, one normally applies the Principle of Bivalence. From WP:

the semantic principle (or law) of bivalence states that every declarative sentence expressing a proposition (of a theory under inspection) has exactly one truth value, either true or false.

So, either the pile is a heap or it is not. How many grains then raises the question of how much which then becomes arbitrary. Why 250 grains do we go from false (0) to true (1) when evaluating a claim "This is a heap of grains"? Why not 225 or 300?
With fuzzy logic, instead of being either true or false, that some given pile of grains is a heap, we are now able to express degrees of truth often represented with decimal values in practice. For instance, up to 100 grains can have a truth value of 0, and then every hundred grains thereafter we can add 0.1 to the truth value of the claim up to 500 grains, and then 501+ grains we can assign a truth value of 1. Now, to have 300 grains, we can say it is now 0.2 true that we have a heap. Thus, we can model "sort of", "almost", "just shy" or any number of natural language expressions to describe a pile of grains.
Fuzzy logic is just one type of many-valued logic. This is an example of how logicians have moved from classical logic to non-classical logic. And it's used in industry in all sorts of ways, such as fuzzy controllers.

Who decides how the truth function varies depending on the number of grains? Who decides what is "fully a heap" (truth value of 1) and what is "fully not a heap"? In my opinion, the fuzzy logic does not completely solve the problem since it cannot answer these questions, only moving the arbitrary part of the answer.

@Taladris It's a fair concern, but as I said, fuzzy logic doesn't solve the problem; rather it dissolves the problem because it is a tool to let a thinker solve the problem. It's like having a nail and no hammer. Upon getting a hammer, one still has to decide how far to drive the nail into the wood, and that is a teleological concern. The same governs the use of a mutli-valued logic for describing a physical state of affairs.

@Taladris The sorites paradox isn't really about where to draw the line specifically (or who draws the line), but more that it's nonsensical to draw any line at all. It's the assertion that anyone saying "N grains is a heap and N-1 is not" is prima facie foolish. It's not the ambiguity of the transition point, but the impossibility of constructing a "reasonable" transition at all. -- While people might disagree on what's the best way to make a fuzzy logic transition, it's moved to a matter of opinion rather than being absurd per se.

@R.M.: (1/2) But almost no one thinks "N grains is a heap and N-1 is not" is not foolish. The sorite paradox is not that sentence, it is in the fact that "there exists a heap", "there exists a non-heap" and "adding a grain to a non-heap does not make it a heap" is a contradictory system, while each statement being reasonable independently. The classic solution is to recognize that some intuitive concepts (heap, being rich, adulthood, species, etc) are ambiguous and may necesitate a part of arbitrary in the definition.

@R.M (2/2) A heap being discrete, any fuzzy truth function will lead to statements like "N grains is not a heap at all (0% heap), but N+1 grains will be a 1% heap". It seems equally foolish to me as "N grains is a heap and N-1 is not". Note that we can still work with arbitrary definitions (in the above sense; of course, all definitions are arbitrary): "large number" is arbitrary, but we can still do Calculus. The delineation between species is arbitrary, but biologists are do a great job understanding the nature.

@Taladris Yes, the existence statements are necessary, but trivial enough I didn't bother to spend my limited characters on them. I'd say there's a difference in kind between the two statements. Saying that N+1 grains is starting to approach a heap - that it's a tiny fractional bit heap-ish - is a rather different thing than saying the single grain is the deciding factor. Arbitrary, rather than absurd. -- Is it that 1% is just too big for you? What if it was 0.001% or 0.000000001%? Is there some level which is non-foolish? (Note the transition doesn't have to be linear. Sigmoidal also works.)

But those existence statements are essential. The problem is not that 1% is too big, it is that it is still arbitrary. And if the maximum jump in truth value (which necessarily exists) is too small (another arbitrary notion), we run into other statements that are difficult to accept; for ex, "If no jump is larger than 0.000000001%, then you need at least 1,000,000,000 grains to make a heap". There are many possible "discrete sigmoids", so still arbitrary.
